# What is this gap, and how do I remove it?

Tags: faces, tabbar

I'm changing the appearance of the `tab-bar`, and I have the following:

[image: emacs tab-line with modified faces, wherein a gap persists between tabs]

There's a gap present between tabs and between the left edge of the frame, despite setting the face attribute `:box` to `nil` on `tab-bar-tab` and `tab-bar`. What is this gap, what face does it belong to, and how can I remove it?

Edit: changing the backrgound color of the `tab-bar` face to match the background color of the `tab-bar-tab` face 'fixes' the issue in that I can no longer see the gap, but I'd still like to know how to fully remove the gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a separator.  It separates tabs as well as the first tab from the window edge. You can either set `tab-bar-separator` to an empty string, thus losing the separator between tabs too. Or just remove the first separator with

```lisp
(advice-add 'tab-bar-format-tabs :around
  (lambda (orig-fun)
    (cdr (funcall orig-fun))))
```